# Migrating Existing, Strapi App from Using Sqlite3 to Using MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, strapi

## I have a local, strapi app (that I have in a git repo) that I want to migrate from using sqlite3 to using mongodb

### I have done the following:

- created a 2nd, temporary, strapi app that is successfully using mongodb from the start (so I have a good mongo instance running locally)
- copied the database.json content from the temp, working-mongodb, strapi app to my existing one. (made sure was in development and ran development version)

From my existing app (from which I want to use mongodb), I

- uninstalled:

  - strapi-hook-bookshelf
  - strapi-hook-knex
  - knex
  - sqlite3
- installed strapi-hook-mongoose

### NOTES:

- the existing app (from which i want to use mongodb) runs successfully if I keep just keep using sqlite3.
- i created the existing app using the quickstart option

### But, I still get this error...terminal output, snippet below

### Terminal Output Snippet:

```
(node:37499) DeprecationWarning: collection.ensureIndex is deprecated. Use createIndexes instead.
(node:37499) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: orm.load(...).buildQuery is not a function
    at buildQuery (/Users/monico_a_moreno/source/.../folder-strapi-poc/node_modules/strapi-utils/lib/buildQuery.js:122:21)
    at Object.count (/Users/monico_a_moreno/source/.../folder-strapi-poc/node_modules/strapi-plugin-users-permissions/config/queries/mongoose.js:18:12)
    at Object.initialize (/Users/monico_a_moreno/source/.../folder-strapi-poc/node_modules/strapi-plugin-users-permissions/services/UsersPermissions.js:502:8)
    at module.exports (/Users/monico_a_moreno/source/.../folder-strapi-poc/node_modules/strapi-plugin-users-permissions/config/functions/bootstrap.js:156:65)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:37499) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:37499) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
[2019-07-03T18:27:15.985Z] warn The bootstrap function is taking unusually long to execute (3500 miliseconds).
[2019-07-03T18:27:15.986Z] warn Make sure you call it?
```

```
    What am I doing wrong?
```

Comment: Tried

* removing `node_modules` and reinstalling (`npm i`)
* re-building first (`npm run build`) 
* running in prod mode (`npm start`)


All to no avail.  

Comment: (...and why don't bullets work in comment fields?!! )

Answer (score 4):

This is cool! I can answer my own question!

Seriously though, I am answering my own question for the benefit of others that might run into the same issue.

**Bottom line:** I had the wrong version of `strapi-hook-mongoose` installed.

**Details:** When I installed `strapi-hook-mongoose`, I didn't specify a version, and so, npm installed `^3.0.0-alpha.13`, and due to the fact that my existing, strapi project is on the (then) latest `v3.0.0-beta.7`, it failed to run (gave the error described in the above description).

**Solution:** Uninstall the package and re-install, ***explicitly specifying*** the version

`npm i strapi-hook-mongoose@3.0.0-beta.7`

Comment: Did you have data you you migrated between the two or did it turn out as a fresh install?